# angular2 multiple-component interaction speed up

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have a page made of six different components. Based on user interaction with one of the components(fixed - made of css elements that have events such as hover and click associated with them), I want to update the display on the remaining five components (highcharts charts- each of them, the update would basically be data series highlight). I currently use observables via service for information transfer (which event occurred at what css element  ->chart components). Although it works fine, it is pretty slow. If I just had one chart component instead of multiple, it works pretty fast and hence I am guessing the delay has something to do with the information transfer. I was wondering if there is a work around for this or other ways to perform the data transfer.

Comment: You can't expect usable responses to this question. No details about what exactly is slow, no code that shows what exactly you are doing. Is it also slow in prodMode or only in devMode. Are you on the latest Angular2 version? Do you use offline template compiler? I guess the best answer possible to this question considering the information you provided is - make the slow parts faster ;-)

Comment: Thanks for these questions. Honestly, all of the aspects you have mentioned, I haven't checked (Complete newbie to app devp programming). I will do that first and hopefully find something through it.

Comment: Also do performance checks on the build output (deployable) not the development setup. Using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` might help to speed up (can't tell from the provided information though).